# Possible to open Chrome bookmarks in a Target unique to link?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, tabs

I have a bunch of bookmarks that I access regularly. They're so many that I might open duplicate tabs, yet I'd prefer not to close them and re-open with all their loading time.

Unfortunately, Userscripts also cannot access chrome:// for the Bookmarks page. So I thought I'd make a bookmarklet to create a global click handler to intercept links and relaunch with their unique URL as its Target. But the links are 4 ShadowRoots deep and isolated from each other... Does anyone have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Give more details, please. Some examples would help.